# Python - Code ignores `if`-statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, sikuli, observers

I just got into Python (Jython) coding a few hours ago and I'm trying to automate Kik messenger (using an Android emulator) using Sikuli IDE.

I am trying to make a region observer that scans for changes, if a change is made, it will check if any commands are found. I am not really sure what I'm doing, but this is the code I got with some help all around the web and documentations:

```
cmdScanLoc = Region(Region(65,762,167,59))

def cmdHelp():
    type("Help")
    type(Key.ENTER)
    cmdScanLoc.stopObserver()

def cmdPing():
    type("Pong.")
    type(Key.ENTER)
    cmdScanLoc.stopObserver()

def changeDetected(event):
    print("Change")
    if cmdScanLoc.exists("1440090739688.png"):
        cmdHelp()
    elif cmdScanLoc.exists("1440090725124.png"):
        cmdPing()
    else:
        print("No Command Found")

def startObserver():
    cmdScanLoc.onChange(50,changeDetected)
    cmdScanLoc.observe(10,background=False)
    Settings.ObserveScanRate = 10

startObserver()
```

Here is the log, after typing !ping:

```
Change

!help
[log] TYPE "Help"

[log] TYPE "#ENTER."
```

It seems to go to `cmdHelp()`, even though I typed !ping. How is that possible? It just completely ignores the `if`-statement.

And here is an image of the region I'm scanning:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6xmo.png
And an image of the images I'm scanning for:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1aH6.png **(code in this image is no longer accurate as you can see)**

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction with this "command scanner" where if a certain command is detected, the appropiate function is called.

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry if this is a really nooby question, I've just been trying for hours and hours, looking up documentation of Sikuli and Python and I just can't get it to work...

Comment: So I've still been trying to get this thing to work now for a long, long time, and it just seems way too instable (It seems to completely ignore the `if` statement, and goes directly to `cmdHelp()` when a change is observed.) Please, I'm asking you, experienced python/jython programmers, to guide me to a better method of doing this kind of thing. :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: It probably doesn't ignore the `if` statement, it's probably `cmdScanLoc.exists("1440090739688.png")' that evaluates to something true.

Comment: I don't know why I got downvoted, because I did do a lot of research and the question seems pretty clear to me. I even added images to make it even clearer... if the person who downvoted me could give me constructive criticism, that'd be a lot better.

Comment: @skyking Could you maybe tell me how I would go around fixing this? I'm really a noob when it comes to Python and Sikuli. It couldn't return true, because the image cannot be found in the region I selected, that's why I'm so lost... Is it stuck in the memory, or?

Comment: I'm probably more noob when it comes to Sikuli so my sugestions is more on the python part. I still think it returns true, to see you could print the result, first assign it to a variable (ie `exists = cmdScanLoc.exists("1440090739688.png")`), print the variable and finally use it in the test (ie `if exists:` instead of `if cmdScanLoc...`). If it as I expect prints as something that's false I'd say that it's a Sikuli problem - and on that part I can't help you.

Comment: @skyking Thanks for your help! You were indeed correct, so I tried changing the method and now it works correctly. I'll post it as an answer for if someone else gets the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much smarter and much faster to do this kind of thing with the region observer than with an `if`-statement. Example code:

```
def cmd1(event):
    print("Command One")
    event.cmdRegion.stopObserver()
    waitCmdAppear()

def cmd2(event):
    print("Command Two")
    event.cmdRegion.stopObserver()
    waitCmdAppear()

def cmd3(event):
    print("Command Three")
    event.cmdRegion.stopObserver()
    waitCmdAppear()

def waitCmdAppear():
    cmdRegion.onAppear(Pattern("1.png").exact(), cmd1)
    cmdRegion.onAppear(Pattern("2.png").exact(), cmd2)
    cmdRegion.onAppear(Pattern("3.png").exact(), cmd3)
    cmdRegion.observe(FOREVER)

waitCmdAppear()
```

Things to not forget:

1. The (event) part when defining a function that's going to be called by the region observer.
2. Stopping the Observer in the event, even if you are going to need it again. Just restart it.
3. In the onAppear, (`region.onAppear([PS], [handler])`) type the handler (ex. `cmd3`) not the function (ex. `cmd3()`)

I hope this will help other people. :)

Comment: Edited my answer as there was a much better method of doing this. I hope I'll help someone with this. :)